# storing the name AND value of a numeric object in a data frame

Tags: r, random, data-manipulation

I randomly sample values from the first row of matrix `A`:

```
                   #1    2    3     4     5    6    7    8    9
A <- matrix(data=c( 0,   0,   0.33, 0.37, 0,   0,   0,   0.3, 0,    #1
                    0,   0,   0,    0,    0.1, 0,   0,   0.9, 0,    #2
                    0.2, 0,   0.1,  0,    0.4, 0,   0,   0.3, 0,    #3
                    0.5, 0,   0,0,  0,    0,   0,   0,   0.5,       #4
                    0,   0.4, 0,0,  0,    0.5, 0,   0,   0.1,       #5
                    0,   0,   0,0,  1,    0,   0,   0,   0,         #6
                    0,   0.2, 0,    0.8,  0,   0,   0,   0,0,       #7
                    1,   0,   0,    0,    0,   0,   0,   0,0,       #8
                    0.1, 0.1, 0.1,  0.1,  0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 ),#9
            nrow=9, ncol=9)

colnames(A) <- c(1:9)
rownames(A) <- c(1:9)


x <- sample(x=A[,1], size=2, prob=A[,1])
```

The result is a `numeric` object that looks, for example, like this:

```
> x
   3    8 
0.33 0.30
```

The 3 and 8 represent important information that I need to store and use for downstream calculations. I have no idea how to extract them - these row numbers seem to be stored as metadata when I `View(x)`:

[image]

How can I reshape the results of `sample()` so that the numeric object that gets output is a vector containing the row numbers (i.e., in this example, I want `x` to equal `c(3, 8)`)?

Comment: `as.vector(x)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```r
A <- matrix(data=c( 0,   0,   0.33, 0.37, 0,   0,   0,   0.3, 0,    #1
                    0,   0,   0,    0,    0.1, 0,   0,   0.9, 0,    #2
                    0.2, 0,   0.1,  0,    0.4, 0,   0,   0.3, 0,    #3
                    0.5, 0,   0,0,  0,    0,   0,   0,   0.5,       #4
                    0,   0.4, 0,0,  0,    0.5, 0,   0,   0.1,       #5
                    0,   0,   0,0,  1,    0,   0,   0,   0,         #6
                    0,   0.2, 0,    0.8,  0,   0,   0,   0,0,       #7
                    1,   0,   0,    0,    0,   0,   0,   0,0,       #8
                    0.1, 0.1, 0.1,  0.1,  0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 ),#9
            nrow=9, ncol=9)

colnames(A) <- c(1:9)
rownames(A) <- c(1:9)

x <- names(sample(x=A[,1], size=2, prob=A[,1]))
x
#> [1] "3" "8"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: that does it :)